# Why has this question been given minus votes?

Tags: support, specific-question, downvotes

I have asked the question *https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46038244/how-to-inactive-octobercms-user* and according to me it is a valid question, because I have not found any way to inactivate a user feature there and hence I asked if there is a way to achieve this. I had researched and mentioned this in my question and at last asked a question.

But to my surprise, it's been given minus votes by other users. I did not understand the fact that, even if they were unable to answer or unable to give any solution or suggestion, why they had just voted as not an appropriate question.

Can someone guide me for the same why it happened?

Answer (score 16):

Your question isn't a programming question. It's about *how to use* a particular piece of software, in this case a CMS. That makes it off-topic, unless the question is about how to use a particular piece of software for software-development purposes (it isn't). People tend to downvote blatantly off-topic questions.

Comment: @MittulAtTechnoBrave votes in meta is different from the main site.. Meta is for discussion regarding things related to main and voting is done more freely. Also votes here has no effect on rep.

Comment: @MittulAtTechnoBrave As suraj said, the voting on Meta is different. Downvotes here don't cost you points on the main site. And the reason for those downvotes is probably the same as the reason on the main site: the question on the main site is off-topic. So, users here are basically saying, "This Meta question has a pretty obvious answer."

Comment: @MittulAtTechnoBrave Your question does not say anything about code. And research alone doesn't make a question on-topic. A well-researched question about gardening would be off-topic here. So is a well-researched question about how to use a CMS.

Comment: @MittulAtTechnoBrave As for your feature request about downvotes: this has been suggested hundreds of times, and it has always been rejected for very good reasons. The moderators and staff have enough to do without several thousand complaints per day about "incorrect" or "unfair" downvotes.

Comment: @MittulAtTechnoBrave I didn't say you had to *include* code. But you didn't  even *ask about* a code-based solution. You haven't addressed the problem, but have only insisted that your question was just fine. Frankly, I'm starting to suspect that you're not interested in why your question got downvotes, and you really just want validation that your question was okay. And your question *did* get an answer; you just didn't like it.